# Require jar files needed to build log4j2

Tags: properties, configuration, log4j2

Where can I download all the jar files needed to compile log4j2 source?

Thanks
Nags

Answer (score 0):

Log4j 2 uses Maven, which should automatically download all the dependencies when you run `mvn clean install`.  Those dependencies will be downloaded from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.